# Generate Word (docx) Files with from Templates (dotx) on Server Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, ms-word

I'm currently working on a project where I have to transfer an existing VB program into a Server Application using ASP.NET.
While I had success doing that there's one thing that I'm struggeling with:

The VB Program was using Microsoft Word Interop to generate Excel files and fill Word Templates with data. While i managed to be able to generate the files locally with Interop I can't get it to work for somebody that is accessing the Application from a client.

I also tried using OpenXML to solve my problem but somehow it always said that the file is corrupt after I tried to fill the bookmarks.

In the end the user shoud be able to download the Word document filled with the necessary data.

What would be the best solution for this problem?

Comment: i would look deeper into your OpenXML issue. Office Interops are not recommended for use on a web site like that. Another problem you will run into with interops is when MS decides to change their API again like they did from 2003 to 2007, it broke a lot of stuff at a previous job. I would suggest sticking with OpenXML, or if you have a budget, look at Aspose. It's similar to interop, but I have used it on server applications successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mostly the same document structure, you can prepare the whole document in Word. Set placeholders in the document like {Placeholder1} {Placeholder2}, parse the XML and Replace the Placeholders with your text, so you must not generate the whole document structure. Only Replace the Placeholders with your text.